# Python, Django and event loop (periodic jobs)

Tags: python, django, pygobject

I am developing a Python applicaton for server that uses Django + WSGI + Apache under Debian Linux. The application has web interface as well as
command line interface (that still uses django models..., just does not use views and templates).
Database backend is SQLite3.

This applications also needs to run some jobs periodically. I wrote a unix-like daemon that uses python-gobject and python-glib, and runs those jobs like this:

```
gobject.timeout_add_seconds(seconds, someCallback...)
gobject.timeout_add_seconds(seconds, someCallback...)
...
gobject.timeout_add_seconds(seconds, someCallback...)

glib.MainLoop().run()
```

I tested it, and there are some strange problems on written data in sqlite db. I think that's because there are two Python instances reading and writing from/to a single sqlite db. One for apache+wsgi and one for my own daemon. (Or event 3 Python instances, when I use command line interface)

My question is, what do recommend me to do? Put those timeout_add and MainLoop in my "dj_survey.wsgi" to run on apache start?

Comment: Wouldn't Celery be an option for you? The [periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) functionality seems quite suited to your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading about it. But this topic doubted me a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404325/django-celery-works-in-development-fails-in-wsgi-production-how-to-debug

Comment: Since I don't need too many features! Just something minimalist and stable.

Comment: Let me change the question: Can I run a jsonrpc server within wsgi environment?

Comment: I saw wsgi-jsonrpc, But I'm afraid django doesn't allow me to have two wsgi applications!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't want to run background processes inside your apache/whatever WSGI environment.

Start them on the shell and use some method to communicate with your background process.

Comment: Thanks, What method should I use to communicate? (I suppose not using D-BUS for server!)

Comment: Should I send http requests from that daemon to apache/django from localhost? (Because apache and then django only responds to these requests)

Comment: Or maybe I better not use WSGI at all.