# How to auto start Django Celery with Apache?

Tags: linux, django, apache, celery, django-celery

I have setup Django and Celery in my production server following these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404325/django-celery-works-in-development-fails-in-wsgi-production-how-to-debug) and it works.

I now need celery to start on boot etc. How can this be done?

I'm running Ubuntu and Apache, do I add something to my virtual host?

Any help, guide to get my started would help. I have Googled but not found anything.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run below command. It will make your /etc/init.d/celeryd start on boot.

```
sudo update-rc.d celeryd defaults
```